# I don't understand how to work with boolean arrays

Tags: java, arrays, boolean, boolean-operations

Question :
Given is a one dimensional array :

```
boolean status[]= {true, false, false, true};
```

i)

```
Evaluate status.length-1
```

ii)

```
Evaluate status[status.length-1 ]
```

This question came in my question paper and till date I have no idea what or how to solve the second part.
I ran the program in my compiler, yet i understood nothing

I got the first answer correct as 3
The second one, I solved like this:

```
4(4-1)
=4(3)
=12
```

and i got it wrong
Here's how I ran it

```
class Abc {
     public static void main(String args[]){
        boolean status[]= {true, false, false, true};
        System.out.println(status.length-1);
        System.out.println(status[status.length-1]);
    }
 }
```

The compiler displays true, can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: You need to learn some Java basics. A good place to start is the Java Tutorials [Arrays section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Thank you Keppil :)
I have my exam tomorrow and am a total newbie with arrays. Your resource will prove helpful for me...

Answer (score 2):

Because  `status[status.length-1 ]` means `status[3]`, which means 4th element of status, which means `"true"`.

Brush up your java basics.

Comment: Thank you. Thank you so much.
I'm feeling so stupid now after realizing this.

Comment: @Keppil - Thanks. That was a typo. Correcting it.